# What is the flux through a square plane cointaining a point charge?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

Consider a square plane of finite area A and let a point charge q be placed on the plane.

What is the electric flux through the plane due to point charge?

I reckon it to be zero as all electric field lines in the plane are parallel to the plane but my books tells it to be non zero.

My question :**Why is flux non zero?**

I do not want exact calculations just a explanation why flux is non zero, as intuitively it looks like zero to me.

Comment: This question need a diagrams since its unclear to figure out position of point charge and square plane by just reading the question

Comment: @Dr_Paradox Consider charge at (0,0,0) and the finite plane with points that satisfy  x<1;y<1;z=0. Does this help?

Answer (score -1):

Its easy, consider the point having charge as **P** over the sheet we can draw 3d radial field lines all around it you can notice apart from parallel field lines(to the sheet), there are other field lines originating through the surface(IMAGINE A 3D SPHERE with point **P**) hence flux is not zero it is infact q/E0(E0 = epsilon)(*through the finite sheet over which charge q is placed)* which could be easily obtained by using gauss law through the 3d sphere we had imagined as a **closed GAUSSIAN SURFACE**. 
don't get confused that field lines are originating from sheet and not passing,infact every surface over which we want to find electric flux we can also assume field lines are originating from surface or passing both are equivalent. if the charge was placed at corner of sheet flux would have been zero as radial field lines don't get any surface to create electric flux. I hope you understand
             (*stay safe amidst chaos of COVID 19* )

Comment: $q \over \epsilon_0$ is the net flux through gaussian sphere,not the sheet. They will be equal if you can show flux through other parts of sphere is zero or cancels out. Can you provide a diagram and justification for the claim?